# jQuery Transverse Up (Through sibs, parents, grandPs, etc.) Until You Find First Instance of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to transverse up the DOM with jQuery to find the first match of a tag.  I've tried `closest`, `prev`, `prevAll`, but they all fail in certain structure circumstances.  If the `p` tag in the example is changed from a sibling to a parent or up it fails.  So I am always targeting the `p` tag. But if you remove the `p` tag in the fiddle (`p tag 1`)... I want `p tag test 2` to highlight... and if you remove `p tag 2` - I want `p tag 3` to highlight. **I am looking for an *arbitrary* way to transverse up. One not based on the selector's location relation to sib, parent, grandP, but on the first find of p tag above said selector.**

```
 <div>(great-great-grandparent)
  <div>div (great-grandparent)
    <p>p6</p>
    <div>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent)
      <p>p5</p>
      <div>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
        <p>p4</p>
        <div>Wrapper
          <!-- <span>span3</span> -->
          <div>li (direct parent)
            <!-- <p>p2-2</p> -->
            <!-- <p>p2</p> -->
            <label class='one'>label1</label>
            <p>p1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rooksstrife/04nq37wr/44/

All these fail to accomplish... **where ever the first p tag is up**.

```
$('.one').prevAll('p:first')
$('.one').prev('p')
$('.one').closest('p')
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but it only goes up 1 level instead of searching up for the first `p`:

```
if ($(".one").prevAll("p:first").length == 0) {
  $(".one").closest(":not(.one)*").prevAll("p:first").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
} else {
  $(".one").prevAll("p:first").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
}
```

Comment: Which element exactly are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The fiddle should show you - in general. It doesn't matter on what element as the issue really is transversing up until the first instance of said (element, class, id, etc.) is found.

Comment: The fiddle correctly selects the previous `p` to the `span`, but you state this is not what you want, so  please be clear. Exactly which element do you want to target?

Comment: `the issue really is transversing up until the first instance of said (element, class, id, etc.) is found` So in this case you want to get the `<p>test4</p>` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan . I am trying to select the first p tag no matter where it is located.  So if you move the p tag in its current prev position it should then highlight the next up p and continue each time you remove the selected p during testing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am always targeting the p tag.  But if you remove the p tag in the fiddle (p tag test1)... I want p tag test 2 to highlight... and if you remove p tag test 2 - I want p tage 3 to highlight.  I am looking for an arbitrary way to transverse up.  One not based on the selector's location relation to sib, parent, grandP, but on the first find of p tag above said selector.

Comment: In which case, so long as `.ancestors` is always present @imvain2 has your answer

Answer (score -1):

You could use parents (https://api.jquery.com/parents/). Parents traverse UP until it meets the passed selector.

```
$("span").parents(".ancestors").find("p:first");
```

Another option is using parents and jQuery's first selector (not CSS):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
$("span").parents("div").find("p").first().css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
});
```

```css
div, p, span * {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>(great-great-grandparent)
  <div>div (great-grandparent)
    <b>test4</b>
    <div>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent)
      <p>test3</p>
      <div>ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
        <p>test2</p>
        <div>li (direct parent)
          <p> Test 1</p>
          <span>span</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest `closest()` in this case over `parents()`, but this should work given the HTML in the question.

Comment: @imvain2 . This would not work as .ancestors is not something I want to key off of.

Comment: @RooksStrife after you changed your question and code, I updated my answer with a working example. I set the first P to B for testing purposes.

Comment: @imvain2 . The issue is this is still not arbitrary.  The parent won't always be a div.